# Woocommerce show me that coupon is not exist, but its in database?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I noticed one strange issue that dont can resolve myself. I have created coupon "welcome10" that i inserted into coupon area in Woocommerce dashboard.. But for some reason, when try to insert coupon in checkout page, write me that coupon is is not exist.

[image]

I [contacted woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-created-coupons-tell-me-that-is-not-valid/), but they tell me too basic informations in style:

- check if coupon exist in DB.
- Check if coupon have valid expiring date.
- check if have particular product settings

but from that i cant debug nothing. Allready tryed all possible debug things like:

- changing the theme, disabling all plugins (except woo) etc, and problem is still there.

Current coupon settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But still same error occured. Any tips how to fix this? [Link](https://www.miloon.eu) to site where problem is showing.

Comment: and its defiantly published and not scheduled?

Comment: Yes its published. See: https://i.imgur.com/njg8mex.png?1

Comment: Any caching plugin installed?

Comment: Fixed myself. Translation plugin inserted badly into database in format: [en]couponcode [de]couponcode makes coupon to be invalid.

Comment: Hehe, u said in your post that u disabled all plugins